# Google Analytics: Tracking multiple URLs as single page

Tags: google-analytics

I run a website where the user is able to create a bespoke page from a template, which is published with a custom URL. For example:

- http://example.com/customer-bespoke-url-1
- http://example.com/customer-bespoke-url-2
- http://example.com/customer-bespoke-url-3

Each of these URLs serve a templated page with custom content, depending upon the URL, but the overall design and layout is the same.

I would like to have the option to track traffic on these pages as a single entity within Google Analytics i.e. combine all the data for these pages together when I need to view the overall effectiveness of the page.

Is there a way I can mark these pages to achieve this?

Comment: I believe you can achieve this through roll-up reporting, but as your question is not code related, it may be best to ask in Webmasters.

Comment: @nyuen Thanks, I've posted the question there as well now.